# Help calculating the limit of an Integral defined in R^2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{k/2}}{1+(x^2+y^2)^{(k+3)/2}}\,dx\,dy$$
without using the change of variable theorem, my idea was to used the Dominated Convergence Theorem but I get stuck calculating the limit, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{x^2+y^2 < 1}\frac{(x^2 + y^2)^{k/2}}{1 + (x^2 + y^2)^{(k+3)/2}} \, dx \, dy = 0$$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{x^2+y^2 > 1}\frac{(x^2 + y^2)^{k/2}}{1 + (x^2 + y^2)^{(k+3)/2}} \, dx \, dy = \int_{x^2+y^2 > 1}\frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} \, dx \, dy$$

The dominating functions should be obvious.

Comment: I found two dominating functions depending on the interval that i choose, But i have a question how do u calculate the last integral without change of variable?

Comment: Do you do Integration by parts?

Comment: Of course it is easy using polar coordinates and somewhat messy otherwise.  This is just the valuation part so I'm not sure why you would not use whatever tools you have to compute the integral.  The point is that the essence of the problem (which can be done without changing variables) is to split the domain, find dominating functions $1$ and $(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}$, recognize they are integrable, and find the limits using $(x^2+y^2)^k \to 0 (\infty)$ for $x^2 + y^2 <1 (> 1)$.

Comment: Alright , Thanks a lot !!!! (: